# TypeScript generic argument that does NOT extend a type

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, it's possible to put constraints on generic type arguments:

```
type Foo = {message: string;};

type Bar<T extends Foo> = {foo: T;};
```

This makes sure that it's only possible to declare `Bar` variables where the `T` parameter has a `message` string property.

However, is it possible to create a type argument constraints so that `T` must *not* extend a given type? For example so that in the `Bar` type above, `T` may be any type that does NOT extend `Foo`?

The only solution I've come up with is to not put this as a constraint but instead a conditional on the type alias value:

```
type Bar<T> = T extends Foo ? never : {foo: T;};
```

This works somewhat well, but it's not the same thing. It won't *prevent declaring* variables of type `Bar<Foo>`, but it will be evaluated to `never`, which will likely cause an error when that variable is then used for something, but still - it moves forward the type check to when the variable is used instead of declared.

Is there a way to instead create the `Bar` type so that it's not possible to even declare `Bar<Foo>`?
I tried using `type Bar<T extends {message?: never;}> = ...` but this does not allow `Bar<string>` or even `Bar<{a: number;}>`.
It's also not possible with circular references in the type constraint: `type Bar<T extends (T extends Foo ? never : T)> = ...` as this gives an error.

**Edit**: Adding an example of this scenario as per requested in the comments:

I have code where you may pass a *value or something that produces that value*. For example that could be passing `T | Promise<T>`, or a thunk `T | () => T` etc, and it might make sense to prevent `T` from being something that may be mixed up with the thunk etc.

Concrete example:

```
interface AsyncResolver<T> {
  get(): Promise<T>;
}

type Resolvable<T> = T | AsyncResolver<T>;

function resolve<T>(resolvable: Resolvable<T>) {
  if ('get' in resolvable) {
    return resolvable.get();
  }
  return resolvable;
}
```

This works until some day when someone tries to have a `Resolvable` of a type which *also* has a `get()` method; then `resolve` would not know if the passed value is an `AsyncResolver<T>` or `T` itself.

This could of course be solved in other ways, such as making `AsyncResolver` into a class which may be tested with `instanceof`, using a unique `symbol` to detect that an object is an `AsyncResolver`, etc etc. But I was interested in a way to make it impossible to create an `AsyncResolver` of a type which conflicts with `AsyncResolver` itself - i.e., adding a constraint on `T`.

Since there are other ways of attacking the problem, I'll admit the question may be a bit academic, but that's OK sometimes, isn't it? :)

Comment: That's an unusual requirement. Might be an XY problem. Could you explain why you need this in the first place?

Comment: @Thomas I will update the question with an example.

Comment: I would tackle this by adding a simple `class ConstResolver<T>` whose `get` just returns a value that was passed into the `ConstResolver`'s constructor. Then you'd always pass _something that produces that value_ even if the something is a trivial wrapper. But yeah, the question remains valid, thanks for the context!

Comment: Or you could have `type Resolvable<T> = () => T`, so the caller would have to write `resolve(() => myConst)` instead of `resolve(myConst)` but that seems like a small price to pay.